# if condition for single.php at wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image

Since I have a blog in blogger(it is a images blog), so I recently moved to wordpress.

After importing all posts from blogger to wordpress it is showing post thumbnail image in single post along with the post original image. So I changed the template. It good working for all imported posts.

But I posted many posts after came to wordpress using a plugin for bulk posting. That template showing thumbnail images in main page , category page etc..  But in single post it is not showing original image.

So I changed template again.  Now the images are not showing in imported posts (single post).

So I decided to show separate single.php codes for each category.

So what I need is:
 I gathers these 2 codes.

- code 1:- (single.php of 1st template)
- code 2:-(single.php of 2nd template)

Here I am copying these 2 codes.

In a template single.php code(what ever the template may be) I like to write if condition to solve my problem. I will tell you algorithm but please write the if condition code please. ............

Algorithm:

```
if( categeory_id=14 or 15 or 16 or 17) 
Code 1 here.
else
code 2 here.
```

Thanks to all developers. If it is not possible please suggest me a good gallery theme.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
<?php if (is_category( array( 14,15,16,17 ) ))
{
    //Code here
}
else
{
    //other code
}
?>
```

In the array put the id of the category. If a category isn't in that array then it will run  the other code.

Comment: dude, your code is ok. But after editing single post page is not opening. only main url is opening.  could you tell me a solution please.  Or could you tell me a good template for gallery, photography

Comment: What do you mean it is not opening?

Comment: main website is opening. www.Example.com is opening. But www.example.com/this is testing page.html is not opening(loading) in browser.